# Why does R treat function closures differently when the inner and outer functions are broken out onto separate lines?

Tags: r, function, closures, environment, bytecode

In R, a closure can be used to define a family of related functions, as in the following example:

```
> power <- function(exponent) function(x) x^exponent
> square <- power(2)
> square
function(x) x^exponent
<environment: 0x7fed9ee6b110>
> square(2)
[1] 4
> cube <- power(3)
> cube
function(x) x^exponent
<bytecode: 0x7fed9f21d5b8>
<environment: 0x7fed9e734d58>
> cube(2)
[1] 8
```

However, when I attempt to divide the "inner" and "outer" functions onto separate lines, something strange happens:

```
> finner <- function(x) x^exponent
> fouter <- function(exponent) finner
> square_alt <- fouter(2)
> square_alt
function(x) x^exponent
> square_alt(2)
Error in square_alt(2) : object 'exponent' not found
```

In the first example, when I defined the function `square <- power(2)`, it seems like R took the number 2, created a special environment for it, and inside that environment, it assigned `exponent <- 2`

In the second example, when I defined `square_alt <- fouter(2)`, R apparently didn't create such an environment, but nevertheless a valid function or object still seems to have resulted, as there's no error message after that line.

**Question 1:** What happened to the "2" in `square_alt <- fouter(2)`?  R evidently consumed the 2, but what did R actually do with the "2", instead of assigning `exponent <- 2`?

**Question 2:** Given the way I've defined the `fouter` closure in the second example, (i.e., breaking out the definition over two lines) what are my options for assigning `exponent <- 2` inside the environment of that object--if indeed it's even possible to make such an assignment?

**Question 3:** Why does the `cube` function also have a bytecode assigned to it, in addition to an environment?  Given I created the `cube` function exactly the same way as I did for `square`, why does R give back a seemingly different result in this case?

Comment: Note that when creating the `finner` exponent is not yet defined. Thus it should be a parameter. ie `finner <- function(x, exponent) x^exponent; fouter <- function(exponent) function(x) finner(x, exponent); square <- fouter(2)` but this is just repeating ones' self

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the number of lines you use to define the function. The difference is that `power` is a function that returns a function. The `finner` code just evaluates an expression, it does not return a function. Only functions can contain closure environments and you need the `function` keyword to create a new function.

Comment: `ls(environment(square)); environment(square)$exponent`

Comment: The bytecode is created by the JIT compiler. When you call `power` the first time, the JIT compiler hasn't had a chance to do its job yet.

Comment: @MrFlick: But when I do `base::is.expression(finner)` I get `FALSE`, and when I do `base::is.function(finner)` I get `TRUE`.  This result seems to partially contradict what you are saying.

Comment: It's not a contradiction. Let me clarify.  `finner` is a function that evaluates an expression. It is not an expression itself. It does not return a function when called so no closure is created. A closure is only created when you return a new function. So `base::is.function(power(2))` returns TRUE. That would not be the case for `finner(2)` assuming it could actually run without error.